# SQL Server 2019 standard - Change output of version select

Tags: sql-server, linux

I believe this is very unusual request.

We have migrated our MSSQL instance to Linux and I need to modify output of MSSQL version provided to the application.

One application, which code I cannot modify, does not understand that it is running on Linux and throwing "Unknown MSSQL version" error every time user log in, which is non-acceptable in PROD env.

Does someone please have idea how to do achieve it?

Comment: How to achieve what? How are you getting the version details? Using `@@Version`? You can't change how that works (if so). You need to change the code that is going wrong. If *you* can't fix that, speak to someone who can.

Comment: The application is from external provider, I dont see a code and have no chance to influence it. I am normally working only with Oracle, so this is new to me, thats why I am asking if theres a way to alter the source of this information directly in the MSSQL.

Comment: You could run a trace to identify how the application is determining the version (e.g. `SELECT @@VERSION`, `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY`) but it is unlikely you can do anything to change it unilaterally. It seems you need to contact the application provider to get a software version that supports your SQL platform and version, if one exists.

Comment: So you're saying you can't change the source code for the application, and therefore wondering if there's a way to change the source code for SQL Server? That's a bit of a stretch don't you think? You'll be way better off talking to your vendor and raising a bug ticket.

Comment: So from trace I can see it is using 1. "select @@microsoftversion" and 2. "USE master exec xp_msver ProductVersion".

@Larnu - Yes, that is not a normal approach. That was my attempt to solve it quickly, as the app actully does not matter about it. All tests passed.d

Comment: However thank you all for informations